# Picking block length in a block bootstrap

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, autocorrelation, kendall-tau

I am using the Mann-Kendall test to assess trends in a data time-series.  I believe there is autocorrelation in my data and therefore need to use a block bootstrap to correct for it.  I have plotted the autocorrelation to try to determine the block size to use in my block bootstrap.  I have not found many resources on how to select this block?  Comparing one example to my data I thought I should pick a length of $15$ as at lag $=15$ the points stay within the autocorrelation intervals (blue lines) but another source said $2-4$ is usually a sufficient block length and that a block length of $1/4$ of the sample size ($n$) can make the test insignificant.  My data $n=64$ so $15$ is approaching $1/4$ of the sample size.  How can I tell the best block size to pick from this plot (or another method?)

[image: autocorrelation plot]

Comment: [This answer by @conjugateprior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25721/182174) might be helpful. Two further sources are [Bühlmann & Künsch (1999)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5a4e/382cf6ed63b9fbdcad66338cc4f516926676.pdf) and [Politis & White (2004)](https://public.econ.duke.edu/~ap172/Politis_White_2004.pdf). Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough about the subject to actually write an answer.

Comment: I have seen it written that an optimal block size is given by $O(n^{1/3})$ (http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ADAfaEPoV.pdf) although no proof is provided.  $n$ is the length of the data.  Chapter 7 in 'Resampling methods for dependent data' discusses it at length but so far it is too theoretical for me!

Comment: forgot to leave page number above, page 587.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, worthy question. I've treated block length as a hyperparameter to tune, and plotted how it affected the parameter estimate. $n=1$ is a standard i.i.d. bootstrap, so it helped me visualize how the block bootstrap was affecting the results. Here's a figure to demonstrate, I ended up picking a block size around 20 for this data. Maybe not rigorous, but makes sense to my brain.
[image: a plot of the standard deviation of mean error versus block length, converging at a block length of 20]