# Simulation of correlated stochastic processes based on some time series

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, simulation

I'd like to simulate power output time series of other wind farms based on measured outputs of one (or more) wind farms. Specifically, I have data on power outputs of wind farm `A`:

$$ \mathbf{x}^A = [x^A_1, x^A_2, ..., x^A_T] $$

How can I simulate $\mathbf{x}^B$, $\mathbf{x}^C$, ... during time $[1, T]$?

- There must be some correlations between $\mathbf{x}^A$, $\mathbf{x}^B$, $\mathbf{x}^C$, which doesn't matter as long as it makes sense.
- It is hard to obtain satisfying statistical models for $\mathbf{x}^A$. Even if you do, those must be based on lots of other factors like wind speeds, angles, temperatures, etc ... which will make the simulation too complicated.
- I have thought about bootstrapping for dependent data, but the method is to resample from the same object, so I cannot simulate $\mathbf{x}^B$ by bootstrapping $\mathbf{x}^A$.
- I am trying to reproduce [woods2013simulation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6262462), but it is based on methods in frequency domain, with which I am not familiar. Does anyone have simpler methods?
- Why I want to simulate outputs of other farms is that I don't have enough data.

### Example

My intention can be illustrated by data from [Aneroid Energy](https://anero.id/energy/wind-energy). Power outputs from three wind farms in NSW Australia are considered.

[image: Three wind farms in NSW Australia.]

Their latest power outputs on April 24, 2020, can be visualized by the following three coloured lines. The values are normalized by their own capacities so the `y` axis is the capacity factor. Note that the black line indicates the average wind power output in Australia. Because `SAPHWF1` and `WRWF1` are close to each other, so they are expected to have similar fluctuations.

[image: Power outputs in April 24, 2020]

Now, suppose I only have the series of `SAPHWF1`, how can I simulate those of `WRWF1` and `BODWF1`? Moreover, what if I don't have historical data at all? For example, I imagine there is a new wind farm next to `BODWF1`, how can I simulate a reasonable realization?

### Reference

- [woods2013simulation] Woods, M.J., Russell, C.J., Davy, R.J. and Coppin, P.A., 2012. Simulation of wind power at several locations using a measured time-series of wind speed. IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 28(1), pp.219-226.
- [Aneroid Energy] Andrew Miskelly, 2020

Comment: To me model-free simulation sounds like an oxymoron...

Comment: It is from the answer for [How do you do bootstrapping with time series data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317724/231405). "Model-free" means you use block bootstrapping directly on the original data without any model.

Comment: Bootstrapping is validated by assumptions guaranteeing the empirical distribution is converging. Otherwise, "rubbish in, rubbish out" to paraphrase Babbage.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when I use bootstrapping. But I don't think it can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

[Time series simulation based on a given time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461113/time-series-simulation-based-on-a-given-time-series/461132#461132) might help explain how data can be generated for a user-specified model.

In this regard it is possible to specify a model without having generated one from a given time series. Is that what you meant by your question ?

Generating a simulation from histogram-like input using the percentage for each interval is a feature of a commercially available software that I have helped to develop. It is straightforward to program a similar feature in R or Python .

Comment: If it's easy to establish a general model for power output, the new series can be simulated by MCMC based on a new model with different parameters. The power outputs are non-stationary.