# Significance Testing of Difference in Variances of Autocorrelated Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, autocorrelation, f-test

I have two consecutive time series of different length that both vary around some common mean, but exhibit different variances, see exemplary figures below. Both show quite substantial autocorrelation. There is a large gap between the end of the first and the beginning of the second, so we can ignore correlations between the two series.

How can I test if the variation in the second time series is significantly smaller than the variation in the first time series? Since the autocorrelation is quite large and, hence, samples are not independent, I cannot apply an F-test. Which statistical test can I use? Thanks!

#### edit:

To avoid confusion, I am interested in volatility overall, not in the (Gaussian) noise that remains in case I fit some function (like prophet, or some sinusoids, some MLP) to both time series to remove the autocorrelation.

### First Time Series:

[image: First time series]

### Second Time Series:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem here: Testing the difference in variances *when*?

The time series you've shown are clearly non-stationary. What this means is that there is a pattern over time. More formally, a time series is nonstationary if the distribution of the variables is changing over time. Letting $X_i$ be the $i$th observation:
$$
P(X_i \le x) \ne P(X_{j} \le x)
$$
One common example of nonstationary time series is time series with seasonal trends. The data you've shown clearly exhibit seasonal trends, i.e. the mean changes over time.

Now we see the problem: We can't take the variance for these time series, because for the variance to exist, the mean has to exist, since we define the variance as $E((X - \mu)^2)$). However, asking what "The" mean of this time series is doesn't make sense, because the mean is a moving target. The mean in January is clearly different from the mean in May.

Luckily, the time series looks like it's stationary after removing seasonal trends. I'd suggest the following procedure:

1. Consider your null hypothesis carefully -- what do you really want to test? Do you want to test that, after removing seasonal trends, the time series have the same variance? Do you want to test whether the seasonal component for one model is bigger than for the other?
2. Build a null model that makes the assumptions you want to test. This model will likely take the form of a [SARIMA](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-a-sarima-model-db051b7ae459) model.
3. Choose some test statistic. A good test statistic might be something like the sample variance after detrending your data.
4. Simulate the distribution of your test statistic under your null model.

Comment: I want to test that the variability overall (including shifts in mean and trends) is lower in the second time series. I consider the shifts in the mean as another random process that adds to the variability and not as something deterministic or something that should be first accounted for. The reason is that the I want to test that a novel method that was only applied in the second time series stabilizes the entire process around a fixed mean, not around a varying mean. It's industrial process data, and any variation is bad, noise is bad, trends are bad. It should be as stable as possible.

Comment: @SmCaterpillar in that case, by the law of total variance, the variance of each time series can be computed as the sum of the idiosyncratic variance and the integral of the squared trend. So your test statistic should be the sample squared error (the sum of var+trend). The rest should still hold.

Answer (score 0):

(This used to be an edit to the original message, but a comment requested to post this as an answer instead, so here we are)

### F-Test with discounted Sample Sizes

The autocorrelation violates the iid (to be precise the first i ;-) assumption of an F-test. Consequently, the autocorrelation leads to higher variability of estimated statistics of the series, i.e. sample mean, sample variance etc. Or in other words, the information present in correlated samples about an estimated statistic is less than in uncorrelated samples.

[O’Shaughnessy and Cavanaugh (2015)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15459624.2015.1044603?journalCode=uoeh20) propose a method to perform t-tests for autocorrelated time series data by simply discounting the sample sizes. For large enough sample size $n$ (they say $n > 50$ is usually enough) the discounted sample size $n_e$ is:

$$n_e = n\frac{1-\hat{\rho}_1}{1+\hat{\rho}_1}$$

where $\hat{\rho}_1$ is the auto-correlation of time shift 1:

$$ \hat{\rho}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{n-1} (y_t - \bar{y})(y_{t+1} - \bar{y})}{\sum_{t=1}^n (y_t - \bar{y})^2}$$

**Can I do the same discounting for the F-test?** What I mean is to calculate the F-test statistic as usual with the given sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ of my time series below. Yet, when determining the critical p-value, I use the discounted sample sizes:

$$ p = P(F(n_{e1} - 1, n_{e2} - 1 ) \geq F_{\text{calculated}}| H_0)$$

Consequently, I have a much more conservative requirement, i.e. the variance reduction must be much larger compared to iid samples to show significance. **Is this a statistically sound approach?**

### Update: Confidence Intervals with Block-Bootstrapping

In case I do block-bootstrapping (either non-overlapping or moving, they both yield pretty much the very same stats) with a sufficiently long block length, I get pretty much the same answer as using the discounted F-test above. For my data the discounted F-test is significant for p < 0.01. For block bootstrapping it's significant for p<0.025. I guess this is the expected price to pay for using a model free approach in comparison to a Gaussianity assuming F-test.

For anyone who is interested, here are the details of the block bootstrapping  approach (based on [this blogpost](https://asbates.rbind.io/2019/03/30/time-series-bootstrap-methods/)):

1. I look at the autocorrelation function to pick a sufficiently large block length.
2. I create $n$ moving blocks of length $k$ from both time series. E.g. if

$$y_0, y_1, y_2, ..., y_{n-1} $$

is one of my time series I create blocks of length $k$ as

block 1: $y_0, ..., y_{k}$
block 2: $y_1, ..., y_{k+1}$ ... block n: $y_{n-1}, y_0, ... y_{k-1}$

Note to avoid the bias of less often sampling the beginning or end of the time series, I wrap both time series around to have a circular array.

3. I take a lot of bootstrap samples of $m = \text{round}(y / k)$ blocks with replacement. I stitch them back together to create a lot of bootstrapped time series.
4. I compute for each bootstrapped series the variance. I look at the 2.5 and 97.5 percentile of the resulting variance distribution of bootstrapping both of my initial time series and check if they overlap. They don't, so there's a significant difference.

Comment: You can't use the same calculation for an F-test that you use for the T-test. The autocorrelation-based ESS (effective sample size) is only one specific kind of ESS, which tells you how accurately your time series measures the *mean*, not the variance, of the time series.

However, you can calculate the ESS for the variance by calculating the autocorrelation for the *squared* values of the demeaned data. This tells you the variance in your estimated variance.

Comment: The time-series block bootstrap will give you correct p-values under broader conditions, but the problem is that block bootstraps have very slow rates of convergence.

Comment: However, a bigger problem would be that the time series is clearly not stationary, and therefore none of these tests are applicable.

Comment: Even if the non-stationary is considered also a random influence of my random process? Like a double stochastic process?

Answer (score -1):

## Update: This turns out to be an answer to a different question. Disregard.

---

There may be a specialised method to do this, but in general you can answer your question by **whitening** your time series to eliminate the autocorrelation.
This simplest way to do this is to fit a curve to the data, ensuring that the *residuals* from this curve aren't autocorrelated, and then comparing the variance of the two sets of residuals.

How to fit this curve depends on your problem. You could do something simple like a rolling average or lowess, or something more sophisticated like a seasonal model. It might also be worth looking at the [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) package.

Comment: A good answer to the wrong question cannot substitute for an answer to the right question. The OP is interested in the variance of the original time series, not some residuals.

Comment: Are  you sure? I don't think it's obvious from the OP whether they're interested in noise or volatility.

Comment: @RichardHardy is right, I am interested in volatility overall, not in the noise on top. In both time series the uncorrelated (Gaussian) noise should be equal as both are collected using the same procedure with the same measurement noise.

If you want to think in residuals, then the question would be: If I subtract the common mean (just the mean, not some sophisticated fit like prophet) value from both time series, are the residuals of the second series smaller than of the first.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, I suspect using a [block bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25721/42952) and calculating the variance of the bootstrap samples might work, but I don't know enough to put this as an answer.

Comment: I am not sure how block-bootstraping would help me. Isn't block bootstrapping used to calculate statistics on stationary snapshots of the time series? If I estimate the variance on block bootstrap samples, don't I again get the noise variance on top of the autocorrelated signal, but not the full variance including the slow changing signal?

I have found another possible solution by simply discounting sample sizes, look my new edit. What's you take on that?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar, I suggest to post your solution as an answer rather than an edit of the question.